# How to add new line character in ajax responsetext

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

How to add a new line character in ajax responsetext. I have to return the Exception message containing error code and description which I have to then show using Javascript alert box.

PHP code snippet returning an error exception:

```
echo('Update Aborted\r\n'.$mIAPException->getErrorCode() . ': ' . $mIAPException->getFurtherDetails());
```

Javascript code snippet:

```
alert(client.responseText);
```

This is not working.

Comment: what is happening instead? is it showing null or undefined? are you waiting for a callback (assync) or using sync ajax? usually press F12 and see what the network says in cases like this.

Comment: It is showing as \r\n in the message

Comment: I am using sync ajax and PHP script just echos the message which I am showing in alert box at client side using javascript. But instead of new line the actual characters appear e.g. in alert box message '\r\n' appears. I tried <br /> also but doesn't work.

Comment: Look at @MarcB's answer it is correct

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `"`-quoted strings. In `'`-quoted strings, the `\r` and `\n` chars are nothing special.

```
echo "\n"; // spits out a newline
echo '\n'; // spits out a '\' char and an 'n' char
```